# Python sqlite index out of range error after table drop/add?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.5

I've got a wrapper I wrote around the sqlite3 module that lets me serialize access from multiple threads.  It also lets me automatically migrate tables when I change their definition.  I noticed when I drop a table and re-add it with more columns, I get an index out of range error.  Something like this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
curs = conn.cursor()

curs.execute("CREATE TABLE test (derp TEXT);"); conn.commit()
curs.execute("INSERT INTO test (derp) VALUES ('deedle');"); conn.commit()
print curs.execute("SELECT * FROM test;").fetchall()
curs.execute("DROP TABLE test;"); conn.commit()
curs.execute("CREATE TABLE test (derp TEXT, val REAL);"); conn.commit()
curs.execute("INSERT INTO test (derp) VALUES ('deedle');"); conn.commit()
print curs.execute("SELECT * FROM test;").fetchall()

conn.close()
```

Will print this:

```
[(u'deedle',)] Traceback (most recent
call last):   File "test.py", line 23,
in <module>
    print curs.execute("SELECT * FROM test;").fetchall() IndexError: list
index out of range
```

When executing the second SELECT statement.  Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem, I am getting: >>> print curs.execute("SELECT * FROM test;").fetchall()
[(u'deedle', None)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it works just fine for me
`[(u'deedle',)]
[(u'deedle', None)]`

Comment: What's your sqlite3.version and sqlite3.sqlite_version say?  Mine's 2.3.2 and 3.3.6, respectively.

Comment: 2.6.0 and 3.7.5, running with python 2.7 You should try and upgrade, as this might be a fixed bug. Latest version is 3.7.6.2

Comment: Ah OK, I'm running python 2.5, so that may be the problem.  I'll see what I can do about upgrading.